# I would like to add a column to existing table on Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.19 for osx10.14 on x86_64 (Homebrew)

I made migration file.

```
$ php artisan make:migration add_request_to_users_table --table=users
Created Migration: 2020_07_05_231205_add_request_to_users_table
```

I modified the file migration made like this

```
class AddRequestToUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('request');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```

```
$ php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2020_07_05_231205_add_request_to_users_table
Migrated:  2020_07_05_231205_add_request_to_users_table (0.01 seconds)
```

But the "request" column was not added to users tables. How come?

Comment: can you add more information. If you ran that migration from scratch it should create a table 'users' with column 'request' as a string.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with your code.
if you use the following import :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

It should work.
Try to refresh and check database or db schema again.